# Ubuntu 18.10 does not wake up from hibernate

Tags: dell, hibernate, inspiron, wakeup, lid

i got a Dell Inspiron laptop with Ubuntu installed. When I shortly press the power button or close the lid the system hibernates as it should. 
Now the problem is that when I open the lid, the only way to wake up is either to plug in and out the power cable (which is weird) or to completely restart the system by pressing the power button for a few seconds. I also managed to return to the login screen with ctrl+alt+f1.

What i wish to figure out is how to manage this problem so that I return to the login screen when opening the lid or pressing the power button again.

I'm a noob to Linux so if you need any system info, just tell me the command to execute. :)

thx

Comment: Same issue here with a Inspiron 7373, any news?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following:

```
cd /etc/default/
sudo gedit grub
```

modify this two lines:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

finally: reboot

Comment: well, i tried that. didnt work for me unfortunately...